# RSS Feed template and links to posts - not working URLs

Tags: templates

I have created RSS Feed template based on EE documentation and one online tutorial. Code for it looks like

```
{preload_replace:master_channel_name="blog"}
{exp:rss:feed channel="{master_channel_name}"}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="{encoding}"?>
<rss version="2.0"
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/"
    xmlns:admin="http://webns.net/mvcb/"
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/">

    <channel>

    <title><![CDATA[{channel_name}]]></title>
    <link>{channel_url}</link>
    <description>{channel_description}</description>
    <dc:language>{channel_language}</dc:language>
    <dc:creator>{email}</dc:creator>
    <dc:rights>Copyright {gmt_date format="%Y"}</dc:rights>
    <dc:date>{gmt_date format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s%Q"}</dc:date>
    <admin:generatorAgent rdf:resource="http://expressionengine.com/" />

{exp:channel:entries channel="{master_channel_name}" limit="10" dynamic_start="on" disable="member_data|pagination"}
    <item>
      <title><![CDATA[{title}]]></title>
      <link>{title_permalink='site/index'}</link>
      <guid>{title_permalink='site/index'}#When:{gmt_entry_date format="%H:%i:%sZ"}</guid>
      <description><![CDATA[{summary}{body}]]></description>
      <dc:subject><![CDATA[{categories backspace="1"}{category_name}, {/categories}]]></dc:subject>
      <dc:date>{gmt_entry_date format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s%Q"}</dc:date>
    </item>
{/exp:channel:entries}

    </channel>
</rss>

{/exp:rss:feed}
```

Everything works fine except links to posts.

Based on above I can tell that URL generated based on the 'URL title' is not working, but when used 'Pages URI' page loads fine.

Link to the RSS feed: http://www.childrensmedgroup.com/index.php/site/feed

Is there any way to replace title_permalink with page_uri in the RSS feed template?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have answered myslef:

```
  <link>{page_url}</link>
  <guid>{page_url}#When:{gmt_entry_date format="%H:%i:%sZ"}</guid>
```

Comment: Please, mark your answer as correct.